# Passing JSON array to list prop : type check failed for prop "list". Expected Array, got String

Tags: json, vue.js

I have a json object, called jsonObject, which contains an array called tracks. I am using this.jsonObject.tracks as an array in my methods and my template (using v-for) and Vue does not complain about that. But I have an issue with this part of my vue template :

```
    <draggable element="ul"
           :options="{group:'track'}"
           list="jsonObject.tracks"
           :move="onMove"
           @end="onMoveTrackFinished">

                [......]

    </draggable>
```

I am getting the error, which is due to the list prop :

```
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "list". Expected Array, got String.
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you forgot the ':' in front of list=""